# Beamer Outline Problem

Tags: beamer

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=alerted text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{fg=structure}
\begin{frame}<beamer>
 \frametitle{Outline}
 \vspace{-4ex}
   \begin{columns}
     \begin{column}{.60\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-12}, currentsection, hideothersubsections]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.40\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={13-30}, currentsection,  hideothersubsections]
        \end{column}   
          \end{columns}    
  \end{frame}
}


\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{exe}[1][]{\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Esempio: }}{\medskip}


\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}   

\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=unime,fg=white}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       PRESENTATION INFO        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author{XXX}
\title{ABC}
\subtitle{\large{CDE}}
\institute{{\bf COurse} \\ \vspace{2ex} Department \\Uiversity}
\date{January 2018}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       SLIDE DEFINITIONS       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-12}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={13-30}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -0.1cm}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{B}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{C}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{D}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{E}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{F}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{G}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{H}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{I}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{J}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{L}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\section{A}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{K}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{M}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{N}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{O}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{P}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Q}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{R}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{S}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{itemize}
\item A b C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem I face is the following. When I show the outline right before each section to make the reader aware about the development of the discussion, the space between titles of sections is really too much. In fact, I cannot show the title of the last sections. Is there any way I can reduce the space between the title of sections in the outline that appears before each section? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you use subsections?

Comment: @samcarter No. I do not use subsections.

Comment: Then simply remove `hideothersubsections`

Comment: You don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer. `\usepackage{multicol}` is probably also unnecassary, as beamer has it's own column mechanism.

Comment: And please do not load the same package multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without `hideothersubsections`. As you don't use subsections, you don't need it anyway.

```
\documentclass[t,11pt]{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=alerted text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{fg=structure}
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-12},currentsection]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={13-30},currentsection]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-12}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections={13-30}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{B}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{C}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{D}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{E}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{F}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{G}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{H}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{I}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{J}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{L}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{A}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{K}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{M}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{N}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{O}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{P}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Q}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{R}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{S}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```